# I want to run flutter code in web it return blank page, I waited one hour but still it didn't show code output

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, dart

I have executed my flutter code on my web page it stayed blank
[[image: chrome web page just blank white like ][1]]

[this my index code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQIQS.jpg)[![][image: this is console message][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxpg7.jpg)][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxpg7.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried to see logs or errors on Developer Tools?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command:

```
  flutter run -d chrome --profile
```

Comment: thank you, sir, for your kind reply, I will definitely ask more questions because of honourable and kind teacher.